# Is "put in all" grammatic for written english?

Tags: word-usage

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=249)

> if you want to you can go ahead and put
>   in all your bottoms and then put in all
>   your tops

I guess "put in all" is easy to understand in everyday speech.

The question is, is that grammatic for written english?

Comment: For me, this is more of a colloquial talk. I wouldn't write something down the way he has said it, however, I know exactly what he's saying. Grammatically I believe it would be incorrect.

Comment: The grammar is fine, but there isn't really a phrase "put in all", per se.  It breaks down to "(put in) *= verb phrase* (all your tops) *= noun phrase*".  So because you can "put in" any noun phrase, and because "all your tops" is a valid noun phrase, the overall construction is acceptable.

Comment: I don't see a problem if this is an instruction for washing bikinis.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for your comments. Would you please write that content down in your style to give me some inspiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is about building a framework that includes pieces of wood along the bottom of the intended structure ('bottoms') and pieces of wood along the top ('tops').

Both the tops and the bottoms need to be incorporated into the structure ('put in' - a perfectly grammatical term).

The speaker is saying that you can do that for the bottoms and then for the tops.

None of what he says is colloquial. It is certainly not ungrammatical. You just have to understand that 'bottoms' and 'tops' refer to pieces of wood at the bottom or top respectively of the intended structure.